# How to find the number of null elements in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I want a way to find the number of null elements in a DataFrame which gives just 1 number not another series or anything like that

Comment: Welcome to stackverflow, please try adding minimal reproducible example of what you intends to perform [https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you could use pd.isnull() and sum:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1], [2,2,np.nan], [3,np.nan, np.nan]])
pd.isnull(df).values.sum()
```

which gives: 3

Comment: Are there any other ways of doing it?
Appart from
pd.isnull(df).values.sum()

And how do you write code blocks in Stack overflow?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get all null values from the dataframe and count them:

```py
df.isnull().sum()
```

Or you can use individual column as well:

```py
df['col_name'].isnull().sum()
```

Answer (score -1):

This code chunk will help

```
# df is your dataframe
print(df.isnull().sum())
```